# Address already in use: Why is Python listening on whatever port I specify for Supervisord?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django, supervisord

Server side processes are not my strong point and I keep hitting a wall trying to get my `Django Channels` application on Digital Ocean on Ubuntu 16.04 using `Nginx` as the main webserver and `supervisord` to run and manage `Daphne`.

I'm getting an error in `supervisord.conf` saying

```
Could not create FastCGI socket [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I stopped `Nginx` then restarted `Supervisor` to see if it would reset port `7000` and allow it to connect but the error is still there.

When I check `sudo netstat -lnp | grep :7000` I see

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11526/python
```

When I kill that instance and restart `supervisord` it appears again, so `supervisord` is obviously starting python then claiming it can't connect to the port because something is already listening.

I'm sure there is some kind of circular logic going on here, but I'm using `supervisord` to manage `daphne` which is an asgi server for `Django channels`.

From the [Django Channels deployment docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html)

> We’re making Supervisor listen on the TCP port and then handing
>   that socket off to the child processes so they can all share the same
>   bound port:

My supervisord config file

```
[fcgi-program:asgi]
# TCP socket used by Nginx backend upstream
socket=tcp://127.0.0.1:7000

# Directory where your site's project files are located
directory=/home/me/myapp/src/myapp

# Each process needs to have a separate socket file, so we use process_num
command=daphne -u /home/me/daphne/run/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd:fileno=0 --access-log - --proxy-headers myapp.asgi:application

# Number of processes to startup, roughly the number of CPUs you have
numprocs=4

# Give each process a unique name so they can be told apart
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

# Automatically start and recover processes
autostart=true
autorestart=true

# Choose where you want your log to go
stdout_logfile=/home/me/daphne/logs/asgi.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

> Nginx has to be told to proxy traffic to the running Daphne instances.

my nginx config

```
upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
    }

    location /media/  {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = www.myapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = myapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: You still haven't gotten rid of supervisord and switched to systemd?

Comment: Haha Michael you need to help me I don't know how!

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was setting up a Django Channels app with nginx and Dapnhe and had very similar adventures. You can check [my older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304883/configuring-supervisor-for-daphne-django-channels) on this topic for more info.

But generally:

- Your `command` command looks suspicious - make sure the directory where the socket files are to be located exists.
- Next, `--fd:fileno=0` - I presume you wrote it this way because of the bug described [here](https://github.com/django/daphne/issues/234), however, it's been fixed and you can simply use `--fd 0`.
- Apart from that, the socket address in the Supervisor configuration should match the upstream specified in the nginx configuration which is not your case (the ports differ).